# State Machine: How to add code for java lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, java-11, state-machine

I am trying to implement a state machine using the Java lambda function. I have created a state machine and some java lambda functions. `But the code editor does not support java`.

Upload from option is available here with 2 different formats:

1. .zip or .jar file
2. Amazone s3 location

[image]

What kind of file do we need to upload over here? Can anyone show me some sample files? Is there any pom file we need to upload for the working of state function?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html

You can package your code into jar or zip file and can upload here.

Comment: @PankajYadav Are we uploading the java project .zip file? How we are creating the deployment package? Should I use Eclipse or any other platform for creating the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For java lambdas we can upload jar file as well as zip which can be created by gradle and maven [plugins](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html) mentioned in the article.

Also lambda now supports container so you can also use [container image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-image.html).

There are also few popular frameworks you can use to deploy java lambda as native image like [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda) or [Micronaut](https://guides.micronaut.io/mn-application-aws-lambda-graalvm/guide/index.html).